# 偷看一眼 sounds like "Ta kan yi yan": wrong lyrics (as happened with 一切都这么美好 which is sung as 一切都变得美好) or weird pronunciation?

Tags: meaning, pronunciation

In the song [忘不了](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GMgbfZLy_g) by Teresa Teng (lyrics [here](http://michelegorini.blogspot.it/2017/08/all-chinese-songs-i-have-met.html)), one line goes:

> 偷看一眼

That is, according to online lyrics. Except in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GMgbfZLy_g), both at 00:25-00:26 and at 1:18-1:20, I hear:

> Ta kan yi yan

So are the lyrics wrong, or is it me mishearing, perhaps its /t<sup>h</sup>au/ with the /u/ being almost undetectable, and that is some regional/dialectal pronunciation? How should it be spelt if "Ta kan yi yan" actually makes sense?

**Edit**

While browsing Youku to respond to @dan's comment with a Youku video, I found [this](http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMjA5NTQ3MTky.html?spm=a2h0k.8191407.0.0&from=s1.8-1-1.2&f=20081278), where the line is:

> 他看一眼

That certainly matches the sounds I hear, but what does it mean?

Comment: Perhaps 踏看？ So "I inspect quickly" or the likes?

Comment: can't play youtube here. :(

Comment: @dan See the edit.

Comment: 他看一眼: he caught a glimpse

Comment: @dan That would have been my guess, but who is "he" in this song?

Comment: I really don't know. But it seems that 偷看一眼 makes more sense according to the context, because it has another line 再看一眼. Maybe, some dialect pronounce 偷 as 'ta', which I don't know. Or it could be just in music, that kind of pronunciation change is acceptable?

Comment: 邓丽君 often says 'di' instead of 'de' too, speaking of mispronunciations..

Comment: @Ravi and liao for le, but those are not one-offs nor even just her thing. Is there any other example of her or any other singer saying ta for tou?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to make sense of a tweet-length song is hard, but since the song is from a romance movie in 1980, it could be a boy meeting a girl for the first time.

- His first glance warmed her and brightened her world.
- His second glance established the fond love and sealed her fate.

That is all I can think of.